# Проблема с ссылками на Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

catalog/view/theme/journal2/css/j-strap.css?j2v=2.15.4
lowenet.biz" - ко всем стилям и скриптам добавляется такая приставка,скорее всего с самой темы. По файлам шарил и нигде не нашёл как это удалить. Возможно ли как-то решить эту проблему через htacess?

Comment: catalog/controler/common/header.php или catalog/controler/common/footer.php

Comment: Я бы не рисковал использовать "ломанные"/варезные модули и темы для интернет-магазина, рискованно очень...